# Java Performance Issue - Tomcat WebappClassLoader locked

Tags: java, json, performance, struts, tomcat7

I have been facing this strange issue from past few days while doing the performance test of my product, i am using java 6,struts 3 framework and tomcat 7 server

During performance test we start a load of thousands of UI requests hitting the server initialy it runs fine but after couple of hours the requests start getting blocked followed by a spike in CPU usage to 100% and even the UI becomes inaccessible.when i took the thread dumps to analyse the issue below is what i am getting consistently.

```
""http-nio-8443"-exec-1305" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f0458538000 nid=0x56dd waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f04345c9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1663)
    - locked <0x00000000a162f0c0> (a org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at java.beans.Introspector.instantiate(Introspector.java:1448)
    at java.beans.Introspector.findExplicitBeanInfo(Introspector.java:431)
    at java.beans.Introspector. (Introspector.java:380)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:232)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:218)
    at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:169)
    at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:152)
    at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:120)
    at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:88)
    at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:90)
    at com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:119)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:348)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:253)
    at com.facetime.imauditor.sreach.action.CustomRequestInterceptorJson.intercept(CustomRequestInterceptorJson.java:69)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:121)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:504)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.facetime.imcoreserver.registration.AbsoluteSendRedirectFilter.doFilter(AbsoluteSendRedirectFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:369)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1532)
    - locked <0x00000000abb53778> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

And below is the statistics of threads.

```
Threads locking monitor=1
Threads sleeping on monitor=0
Threads waiting to lock monitor=1097
```

Any help in this regards would really be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: have you compared the garbage collector activity to the cpu spikes you encounter?

Comment: the garbage collector seems to be working fine wemu.

Comment: in the above dump, what is "waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f04345c9000]" doing? Maybe we are looking at the wrong thread.
Is the memory consumption ok or does it increase a lot when increasing the user load?

Comment: the memory consumption is ok, it just that the response time for the UI requests is getting increased and after certain point the requests are getting timed out.The above thread dump is holding the lock and the remaining threads(1097) are waiting for it to release the lock.The waiting requests do similar operations as the one which  is holding above.

Comment: the number of connections to the database or the tomcat connection pool or the number of allowed sessions is not the issue? have your tried to attach a profiler to the jvm to have a closer look what is done? hard to say if your running against a limit or if just a shared collection is badly synchronized. I also would not skip memory issues. Maybe the threads have to work to increasing amounts of data and dont finish because of that.

Answer (score 3):

this is a bug in struts2 json plugin:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3902

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

I recently were facing a similar problem. Sometimes when a web application is not well programmed, it may not clean up network (TCP) sockets correctly... for example the database connection classes. Leading to too many open filedescriptors on the host (Tomcat JVM) process. And that may lead to the same in-responsibility you are facing.

So, in my case i solved the problem by designing the database connection in a per thread basis using ThreadLocal generic. This is managed in my Web-Apps service managed bean.:

```
private static ThreadLocal<YourConnectionClass> connection = new ThreadLocal<YourConnectionClass>();

public static YourConnectionClass getConnection(){
    if (connection.get() == null) connection.set(driver.getConnection());
    return connection.get();
}
```

This will ensure that per tomcat executor thread only one TCP socket will be opend. If that problem applies to you an you add a similar fix to the one i mentioned, your problems will dissapear. well, but its still just a "guess". Tou can verify if that applies to you by simply entering this into the servers unix/linux console:

```
netstat | grep <YOUR_TCP_PORT>
```

or by using lsof (list open files). Because TCP sockets handled like open file handles.

```
lsof <YOUR_JVM_PID>
```

If the number of open sockets after tomcat start is less or little and on the other hand is devastating high when your in-responsibility problem occurs, then you may have an open socket file descriptor leak.

As a second guess you may also have a HashTable memory leak that can be caused even in Java when not cleaning up a HashTable of Java objects correctly (somewhere in the web-apps server code). But as i can read in the above comments, thats probably not the case.

cheers,

will

---

**My older Answer:**

I bet its the Garbage Collection Strategy.

Try using another one by setting the correct JVM OPTS:

```
-XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SurvivorRatio=2 -XX:NewRatio=8
```

Check this links:

http://www.petefreitag.com/articles/gctuning/

http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/miscellaneous_java/Java_Options_For_Garbage_Collection.html

Comment: thanks for the reply will, i tried with the above JVM options too but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be fixed by upgrading to Tomcat 8.0.16 or greater and setting Loader class to org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader.

In [TOMCAT_HOME]/conf/context.xml, add the following line and restart

`<Loader loaderClass="org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader" />`

We had a similar issue where Hibernate and Spring JDBC would try to convert a db resultset row to an object. This locking behaviour severely impacted tomcats running lots of threads with large resultsets.

I would recommend users running Hibernate and Spring JDBC application on Tomcat7 to Tomcat 8 with ParallelWebappClassLoader turned on for a much better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a similar issue due to synchronized on WebappClassLoader; shows up any time there is a high number of loadClass calls - which many 3rd party libraries do unfortunately. The ideal fix is to not call loadClass all the time, however that might not be an option.

This stems from a change introduced to Tomcat as part of bug 48903/44041/48694 to fix a deadlock some users were experiencing.

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=927565

In my opinion, the fix is overly pessimistic on synchronize-ing, hopefully I can get a fix accepted that will allow the local cache to be checked prior to entering the monitor; which should make this go away.